# Continuity of a function.

Tags: calculus, continuity

I suppose that if i solve the first item (i) could solve (ii) either, but i make no idea how to start it.

Let $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ a continuous fuction.

(i) Show that if $f(x) = 0 \ $ for all $x \in \mathbb{Q}$, then $f(x) = 0 \ $ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

(ii) Show that if $f(x) = 0 \ $ for all $x \in A = \{x \in \mathbb{R} : x = \pm \frac{p\pi}{2^q}, p \in \mathbb{N}, q\in \mathbb{N}\}$ then $f(x) = 0 \ $ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ .

Comment: Suppose there is some $x$ with $f(x) = c \neq 0$. Can you show that this implies that $|f(y)| \geq |c|/2$ for all $y$ sufficiently close to $x$? And can you obtain a contradiction from this?

Comment: why it becomes a contradiction?

Comment: are you working with the sequential continuity definition or the $\delta - \epsilon$ definition?

Comment: It becomes a contradiction because there are rational numbers arbitrarily close to $x$.

Comment: i´m working with $\epsilon 
/\delta$ definition @DonlansDonlans

Comment: ah! now i understand your point

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

(i) Every real number is the limit of a sequence of rational numbers – e.g. its decimal approximations with $n$ digits

(ii) What is the question?

Comment: sorry, i forget it lol.

Comment: i can´t see how it helps me.

Comment: If $f$ is continuous, $f(\lim_n x_n)=\lim_n f(x_n)$. What is the sequence $\bigl(f(x_n)\bigr)_n$ if $x_n$ is rational?

Comment: i don't know about sequences, maybe is this...

Comment: You've necessarily learnt that continuous functions  preserve limits…

Comment: Yes, I know that. but this sequence, I have no idea what it is

Comment: For instance, fo $\pi$, it is $3,\,3.1,\,3.14,\,3.141,\,3.1415$, &c.

Comment: Now i get! thanks, i think i can prove it.